# What's the differences beteen "put" and "force" in MappedByteBuffer?

Tags: java

After I  get a MappedByteBuffer from FileChannel, I use put method on this buffer, sth like:
buffer.put((byte)'a')
then I found that the file content was written one characheter 'a'. It is the same with "force" method in MappedByteBuffer. is there any different between 'put' and 'force'?

Answer (score 1):

`put()` stores data in the buffer, `force()` tells the operating system to flush the buffer to disk.

In modern operating systems, you won't be able to detect the result of `force()` by looking at the file, because separate references to the same file share an underlying OS buffer. You might be able to detect the difference by pulling the power immediately after the `put()`, because the OS won't immediately write changes to disk.

Calling `force()` frequently is not recommended, because it (1) causes a context switch into the kernel, and (2) ties up your IO channel.

Also note that `force()` isn't a guarantee that the data will be on the disk, because disk drives have their own buffer caches. It's entirely possible to lose power after the OS thinks it's written the data, but before the drive moves it from the cache to the platter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Does the "put" method will change the content on disk?

Comment: @uuball - Eventually. `put()` changes the buffer, eventually the OS will write the buffer to disk, and eventually the disk will write the blocks from its internal cache to the platter.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html#force%28%29)

> Forces any changes made to this buffer's content to be written to the storage device containing the mapped file.
>   If the file mapped into this buffer resides on a local storage device then when this method returns it is guaranteed that all changes made to the buffer since it was created, or since this method was last invoked, will have been written to that device.
>
> If the file does not reside on a local device then no such guarantee is made.
>
> If this buffer was not mapped in read/write mode (FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE) then invoking this method has no effect.

Flusing memory mapped files to disk requires a system call, on linux this is typically accomplished by invoking `fsync`, force causes this invocation to occur, put does not.